# Invalid Chai property in Vitest

Tags: react-testing-library, vitest, testing-library

I have this Vitest test:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
    import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
    import { StyledNativeTimePicker } from 
       '../timePicker/StyledNativeTimePicker.jsx';

    ...

    it('Shows the time correctly', async () => {
    const time = '12:00';
    render(
        <StyledNativeTimePicker
            time={time}
            timeChanged={() => {}}
        ></StyledNativeTimePicker>
    );
    const testInput = screen.getByRole('input', { type: 'time' });
    expect(testInput).toHaveValue(time);
   });
   ...
```

Now I get this error `Error: Invalid Chai property: toHaveValue`. Any Idea why when Chai is not installed?

Comment: Chai _is_ installed, by Vitest. [_"Vitest provides `chai` assertions by default and also `Jest` compatible assertions build on top of `chai`"_](https://vitest.dev/api/expect.html#expect) - neither includes `toHaveValue`, perhaps you intended to use [Jest-DOM](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavevalue).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create `setupTests.js` file, then connect it to the config. You may have to install `jsdom` as a dependency to the project.

**setupTests.js**

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: ["./setupTests.js"],
  },
});
```

links: [Github problem](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/439#issuecomment-1715184115) and [Configuring Vitest](https://vitest.dev/config/#configuring-vitest)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed this

```js
npm i vite-tsconfig-paths
```

and added to my vitest config : vitest.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
})
```

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be installed as a dependency of vitest

Try adding

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest';
```